# websocket interrupted while using window.location.assign on firefox version 39

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, websocket

Error:

> The connection to wss://localhost:28443/Administration/sessionCheck?d22c6c8e-61b4-41d3-b447-6436b5b631c9 was interrupted while the page was loading.

I am new to websocket,angular js.Using websocket in the single page - web application to understand whether the server is alive.

In this when I try use window.location.assign(url) to download the zip from the application on firefox the websocket connectivity is lost & i have tried to search this on this forum but i didn't got matched answer.

Websocket is interrupted when i use window.location.assign(url) page on firefox. This works seamless on chrome and IE.

I have also implemented the fixed on the client side by checking on window load if the socket is open or not:
Inside the controller

```
window.onbeforeunload  = function () {
    $scope.webSocketFinalize();
};
```

Main Controler code

```
function webSocketProvider($scope, $location, $window, heartbeat_interval, $translate, $timeout) {
    $scope.websocketHB = null;
    $scope.startWebSocketHeartBeat = function(headerValue){
        var wsUri = "wss://"+window.location.host +
        window.location.pathname+"severHeartBeat?"+headerValue;
        var heartbeat_msg = '--heartbeat--', missed_heartbeats = 0;
        websocketHB = new WebSocket(wsUri);
        console.log("message 1....: startWebSocketHeartBeat"+websocketHB);
        websocketHB.onopen = function(evt) {
            console.log("opening...2..........");
            if (heartbeat_interval === null) {
                    missed_heartbeats = 0;
                    heartbeat_interval = setInterval(function() {
                        try {
                            missed_heartbeats++;
                            if (missed_heartbeats >= 3){
                                clearInterval(heartbeat_interval);
                                heartbeat_interval = null;
                                console.log("Closing connection. Reason: ");
                                websocketHB.close();
                                window.location.href = '/Administration';
                                $routeParams.auth = '';
                            }else{
                                try{
                                    if(websocketHB.readyState == 1 || websocketHB.readyState == 0){
                                        websocketHB.send(heartbeat_msg);
                                    }
                                }catch(e){}
                            }
                        } catch(e) {
                            clearInterval(heartbeat_interval);
                            heartbeat_interval = null;
                            console.log("Closing connection. Reason: " + e.message);
                            websocketHB.close();
                        }
                    }, 5000);
                }
        };
        websocketHB.onmessage = function(evt) {
            console.log("message 3....: startWebSocketHeartBeat"+evt.data);
            if(evt.data == "--heartbeat--") {
                missed_heartbeats = 0;
            }else{
                console.log("Send Failed:");
            }
        };
        websocketHB.onerror = function(evt) {
            console.log("ERROR:4 " + evt.data);
        };
    };
    $scope.webSocketFinalize = function() {
        if(null!=$scope.websocketHB){
            $scope.websocketHB.close();
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: It would be great if someone can at least suggest an alternative for this.

Comment: Using window.open instead of window.location.assign(url)

Comment: window.open definitely works, however it opens a blank window. Did you try to open it in some hidden frame to avoid it?

Comment: I not sure is good practice for using frame.Just in case multiple browser.

Comment: I agree, and we did a little branching in the code to use the work around for Firefox only.

Comment: Thank you.If you come up with any other solution,kindly suggest.